# How to print the lines of a text file that contain a certain string in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
rpm_list = ['201.abc.rpm', '202.xyz.rpm']
fh_file = open(text_file, 'r')
rpm_found = False
for rpm in rpm_list:
    for line in fh_file:
        if rpm in line:
            fh.write('\n\nSuccess: ' + rpm + ' was found in: ' + text_file + '\n\t at the following line: \n' + line)
            rpm_found = True
    if rpm_found == False:
        fh.write('\n\nError: ' + rpm + 'was not found in: ' + text_file + '\n')
```

If the strings are found in the text file, then I want to print something like:

`Success: 201.abc.rpm was found in text_file at the following line:`

`line 26: abc abc 201.abc.rpm abc abc`

`Success: 202.xyz.rpm was found in text_file at the following line:`

`line 108: xyz xyz 202.xyz.rpm xyz xyz`

My code only prints this for the first element of `rpm_list` twice. It does not print the message for the second element.

In addition, I also want to print a message if the strings are not found in the text file such as:

`Error: 201.abc.rpm was not found in the text_file`

`Error: 202.xyz.rpm was not found in the text_file`

Comment: Switch the order of the 2 `for` statements. Or, after the inner `for` is completed, rewind the file pointer back to the begining (`fh_file.seek(0)`).

Comment: Think about what the value of `rpm_found` will be, when you start searching for the second item, if the first item was found. Also think about where the search process will start looking in the file. Also, please use a `with` block to manage your file handle.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the correct solution:

```
rpm_list = ['201.abc.rpm', '202.xyz.rpm']
fh_file = open(text_file, 'r')

for rpm in rpm_list:
    rpm_found = False
    for line in fh_file:
        if rpm in line:
            fh.write('\n\nSuccess: ' + rpm + ' was found in: ' + text_file + '\n\t at the following line: \n' + line)
            rpm_found = True
    fh_file.seek(0)
    if rpm_found == False:
        fh.write('\n\nError: ' + rpm + 'was not found in: ' + text_file + '\n')
```